# Flexbox Multi Class Selector in SCSS

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

Is there any shorthand syntax for flex-basis listing in scss? I am setting them for 10+ multiple fields. Providing simple example below,

Just curious if multi-class selector exists.

**Current:**

```
.fielda {
    flex-basis: 20%;
}

.fieldb {
    flex-basis: 50%;
}

.fieldc {
    flex-basis: 30%;
}

etc,
```

**Does Similar Ideal Syntax Exist?**

```
.fielda, .fieldb, .fieldc{
     flexbasis: 20%, 50%, 30%
 }
```

We are using Angular 7 framework, looking for similar shorthand syntax

Comment: Your Ideal isn't valid CSS so I'm not sure how that even makes sense.

Comment: hi @ErikPhilips I am looking for something similar anyway to shorten, would be nice, thanks

Comment: No you can't shorten the syntax. That's just how css works. Your "ideal" syntax also doesn't make sense, so it isn't ideal at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It feels like you want SCSS to auto-generate your CSS.  If that's the case you can use:

scss:

```
@for $i from 1 trough 4
  .flex-basis-#{$i} {
    flex-basis: 10% * $i;
  }
```

which would yield css:

```css
  .flex-basis-1 {
    flex-basis: 10%;
  }
  .flex-basis-2 {
    flex-basis: 20%;
  }
  .flex-basis-3 {
    flex-basis: 30%;
  }
  .flex-basis-4 {
    flex-basis: 40%;
  }
```

> my css rows are more dispersed, sometimes I may have 12, 38, 8, 42 for different divs

Use a list:

```
$sizes: 12px, 38px, 8px, 42px;

@each $size in $sizes {
  .icon-#{$size} {
    width: $size;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is great, for consective incrementals, my css rows are more dispersed,  sometimes I may have 12, 38, 8, 42 for different divs,  no real pattern, etc  however, will keep in mind

Answer (score 0):

You can set the flex basis of multiple elements by using simple calculation in SCSS as below.

```
$flex-base-value = 10%;

 .fielda {
    flex-basis: 2 * $flex-base-value;
}

.fieldb {
    flex-basis: 5 * $flex-base-value;
}

.fieldc {
    flex-basis: 3 * $flex-base-value;
}
```

This way you will just have change the base value of flex and according style the elements.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I am trying to do shorthand syntax, this does not answer question

Comment: oh alright. Anyways I hope you the answer from @Erik :)